# Customize android?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

Question, I have a HTC Hero with Android 1.5.

The buggy (speed <= 10 kb) network driver bothers me since a long time.
(I saw it can serve 50 kb/s or more, but only temporarely, but then, after a few seconds,  it slows down to < 5kb/s and takes about an hour to come back to 50 kb/s...)
Now HTC is working on 2.1, but whatever... I don't know what takes soooo long.

Basically, what I would need to do is just cross-compile the android kernel for ARM and maybe some installed native apps wouldn't work anymore afterwards.

Is it possible (without big riscs) to compile my own custom android?

Or will I be unable to use the phone afterwards if anything goes wrong ?

Comment: I think the next release will be 2.0 rather than 2.1.  Anyway, just to say that I have had no such problems with my Hero; I've managed speeds of over 1Mbps.

Comment: All I seem to manage is speeds up to 5 kb/s and then dropping to < 1000 bytes per seconds. Only over the phone, though, wireless works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any such bug re: speed, but I also don't own a hero but a Magic.

It is very much possible to compile android on your own. If this is a radio or driver problem though, I don't see how that would help: Afaik some drivers are closed-source so they wouldn't be helped at all.

Comment: Some != all, and in Linux, all the drivers are in the kernel.
Only the closed-source and the rarely used drivers are outside in modules.

Comment: The drivers for your Hero are very likely proprietary and not part of any linux kernel tree. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to do your own custom build, I'd suggest you see if you can use [cyanogenmod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/) in your Hero. They are doing custom android builds for a long time.

Comment: Indeed, compiling it yourself would require that you also extract the proprietary hardware drivers from the Hero -- these are not included in the AOSP tree.

Comment: That assumes that there are no replacement opensource drivers in the linux kernel. Besides, proprietary Linux drivers should be forbidden.